# Changing zIndex on mouseover for overlapping infoboxes

Tags: bing-maps

I've got on my map (Bing Maps AJAX v7) multiple infoboxes with custom HTML content. Since some of them are close, the infoboxes overlapp sometimes.

Also, I would expect that, when mouse is over one of them, it comes to the foreground and (optionnaly) come back to the background when mouse leaves.

So, by using `zIndex` property, I added these lines :

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(infobox, 'mouseenter', function(e) {
  infobox.setOptions({zIndex : 300});
 });
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(infobox, 'mouseleave', function(e) {
  infobox.setOptions({zIndex : 0});
});
```

However, things are going weird with these lines :

- when mouse enters, the infobox makes a jump of location untill next map redraw.
- the mouseleave callback is never called.

I reproduced this on a jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wXFhy/7

Has anyone any ideas on why or how ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the reason of this behavior. However, I changed the technique to obtain what I wanted by using css only (with `z-index` and `:hover`) rather than Javascript and  that works well. See http://jsfiddle.net/wXFhy/8/.

I added these css properties :

```
.FriendPinMap {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:0;
}

.FriendPinMap:hover {
  z-index:3;
}
```

and removed the javascript doing (badly) the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to do with you using custom HTML content via the htmlContent option on the infobox.  I see that your custom content is floated to the left.  I'm not sure why, but it seems to cause problems with Bing maps when you use css floats in your htmlContent.  I commented out the left floats and the jumpy behavior goes away.

http://jsfiddle.net/wXFhy/10/

As for the mouse leave not getting called, it probably has to do with your custom html content as well.  Try starting from a simple div and see if the mouse leave gets called.  If that works, rather than relying on css for laying out your info box, try using tables instead.  I know you are supposed to use css for layouts, but with the bing maps infobox I have found that tables work better for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you @bojin, but actually, it doesn't work quite like I originaly expected.. I've just posted a css only solution that works. But I think also that `float: left;` is a part of the problem.